# Is it possible to install an occupancy sensor switch to control 3 light fixtures?

Tags: electrical

Renovating my bathroom, I wanted to have 3 wet proof light fixtures in the shower/tub area. The source is at the light and the instructions are vague. The sensor is a Lutron MS-OPS6M2-DVR-WH.

Comment: You need to clarify where you wish to locate the sensor/switch. Switches should not be located inside a shower enclosure. So, if you take showers longer than the sensor is set for, the lights will shut off during your shower. 

Answer (score 2):

The wiring diagram in the [manufacturer's documentation](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/369488.pdf) is quite simple.

> [image: Lutron Occupancy Sensor Wiring]

The lines labeled "Hot/Live" and "Neutral", is the feed from the breaker. The "Load" is the light you're trying to control.  To expand it for three lights, you'd wire it like this...

[image: Lutron Occupancy Sensor Wiring expanded]

Notice that the wiring in the switch box does not change. You simply add on additional loads (lights) to the circuit.

---

## NOTES:

- For an occupancy sensor to work, it has to "see" your movement. Which means it will have to be positioned so that it can always "see" you, no matter where you are in the bathroom. This might require a clear, or translucent shower curtain.
- The switch cannot be mounted within the shower/tub area, or anywhere it might get sprayed, splashed, or wet by any means.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, detection is a serious issue in a bathroom with stalls of any kind.   Another place this issue comes up *a lot* is public bathrooms with toilet stalls.

LEDs make this a lot easier to deal with, because you can just leave a light "always-on", at only 3-5 watts it takes no more power than a common "night-light", yet provides gives a genuinely useful amount of light.  In my commercial spaces I do just that, adding an small LED to the fluorescent troffers which are over the toilet stalls.

They also make down-lights with detectors built-in, however, they aren't necessarily tub/shower rated.

For those hardware tinkerers out there, there's an emerging trend: 12 volt occupancy sensors are becoming readily available, and 12V LED bulbs and fixtures have been available for awhile.  That's interesting for bathrooms and pools, because 12V is a much safer voltage unlikely to electrocute anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Can echo though the sentiment that an occupancy sensor can be a pain.

Having a long relaxing bath, eyes closed, not moving.

Then the lights go out and you start flapping around like a deranged bird to switch the light back on.

May also have issues in a bathroom with the heat, can be an issue for PIRs.